# CentOS .NET Core 6.0 installs wrong runtime version

Tags: linux, .net-core, centos8, .net-6.0

These are 2 commands I ran trying to install .net core 6.0 on CentOS 8 Stream:

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-runtime-6.0
Last metadata expiration check: 0:12:04 ago on Tue 23 Nov 2021 17:38:47 UTC.

. . .

Installed:
  dotnet-host-6.0.0-0.6.28be3e9a006d90d8c6e87d4353b77882829df718.el8.x86_64                                                                                
  dotnet-hostfxr-6.0-6.0.0-0.6.28be3e9a006d90d8c6e87d4353b77882829df718.el8.x86_64                                                                         
  dotnet-runtime-6.0-6.0.0-0.6.28be3e9a006d90d8c6e87d4353b77882829df718.el8.x86_64                                                                         
  lttng-ust-2.8.1-11.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                            
  userspace-rcu-0.10.1-4.el8.x86_64                                                                                                                        

Complete!

[/usr/local/bin]$  dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0-rc.2.21470.23 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Install says it installed `6.0.0-0.6` but the actual version is `6.0.0-rc.2.21470.23` and my app is failing with error:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64) was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      6.0.0-rc.2.21470.23 at [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

**Can it be fixed without manual .net install ?**

**SOLUTION (worked)**

1. add repo to the OS:
   sudo rpm -Uvh https://packages.microsoft.com/config/centos/8/packages-microsoft-prod.rpm
2. change it priority to preceed the OS:
   echo 'priority=50' | sudo tee -a /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft-prod.repo
3. install
   sudo dnf install dotnet-runtime-6.0
4. reboot the machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CentOS 8 Stream seems to have an out-of-date version of .NET 6.

That the version is old is kind of my fault; I need to update the package in CentOS Stream 8 (which really copies what's in RHEL 8.6 and that's the one I will fix).

The version showed by `dotnet --info` is correct.

The RPM package versioning is a workaround in that CentOS (and RHEL and Fedora until recently) don't have a way of reflecting pre-release versions of an upstream that is about to a release 6.0. We are forced to use a version "6.0" and Release with "0.X" to say "this is a pre-release of 6.0". I could have called it "6.0-0.6.rc2", but this build isn't even exact "6.0 RC2", it was a pre-RC2 snaphost (commit `28be3e9a006d90d8c6e87d4353b77882829df718` from [dotnet/installer](https://github.com/dotnet/installer/) repository).

If you urgently need .NET 6, here are some options to consider:

- If you need a container, try out `registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/dotnet-60-runtime`.
- Use a manual (not package) install of .NET 6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#manual-install
- Add the Microsoft RPM repository ([repo file](https://packages.microsoft.com/config/centos/8/)) and then use [solution 3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-mixup#solutions) to make sure it take precedence over the CentOS repository.

Comment: yeah I just found out a minute ago that on CentOS 8 - the .net reinstall to 6.0 works fine, but not on CentOS 8 Stream. It is fairly pressing - how long its going to take to update the repository? (I am going to try solution 3 for now :) )

Comment: Updating would probably be a matter of days, if not weeks.

Comment: solution 3 worked (after a reboot). thank you

Comment: Wait... I thought MS wrote that they do not support .Net 6 on Cent OS 8?

Comment: CentOS Stream 8 - which is really the "next version of RHEL 8" (as opposed to CentOS 8, which is really the "current verisn of RHEL 8") -  is not going EOL.  Red Hat definitely intends to produce .NET 6 packages for RHEL 8, and those should show up in CentOS Stream 8.